# How do I group optional strings together

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression which validates
`"Optional str1 as string = ''"`,
but also
`"str2 as string"`
and also
`"str3 as boolean, Optional dtm as date = Now"`

So when `"Optional"` is used there must be a `"="` sign
But `"Optional"` is optional

This is what i have tried:

```
(Optional\s|)(.*)(\s=\s|)(.*)
```

and this is not right. It validates too much.

Any hints?

Comment: It seems like the question you are asking may be a secondary issue to a real problem you are trying to solve. (It looks like you may be trying to validate the syntax of an existing programming language).

If so, you will probably get a higher quality answer if you provide more context around the larger problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

Then either match the string if it contains Optional followed by an equals sign in the string, or use a negative lookahead (if supported) and match the whole line if it does not contain Optional using an alternation `|`

```
^(?:.*\bOptional\b.*\s=\s.*|(?!.*\bOptional\b).+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `.*\bOptional\b.*\s=\s.*` Match the whole line if it contains Optional and an equals sign between whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!.*\bOptional\b).+` Match the whole line if it does not contain Optional
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unmkMz/1)